# rospack find beginner_tutorials failing

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After doing a successful full desktop install of ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu Precise 64-bit, ( overlay too)
I did:

```
$ roscd
$ roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp    (this part worked)
```

then:

```
sam@Mecha:~/fuerte_workspace$ rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.022642 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.011132   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
0.010529   /opt/ros/fuerte/share
0.004067 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp
0.003998 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros
0.002150 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/swig
0.002037 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/swig/1.3.29
0.001495 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/doc
0.001454 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/doc/pcl-1.5
0.001429 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/doc/pcl-1.5/tutorials
0.001376   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/navigation
0.001299 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/doc/pcl-1.5/tutorials/sources
0.000902   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/robot_model
0.000612   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry_experimental
0.000593   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/image_pipeline
0.000474 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/catkin
0.000450   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry
0.000411   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/diagnostics
0.000398   /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
0.000387   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv
0.000371 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/catkin/cmake
```

then:
THIS IS THE PROBLEM:

```
sam@Mecha:~/fuerte_workspace$ rospack find beginner_tutorials 
[rospack] Error: stack/package beginner_tutorials not found
```

My .bashrc file in my home directory has the following source lines where I replaced one source line with another as prescribed in the installation instructions.... and executed . ~/.bashrc

```
# source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash  <---this is commented out
source /home/sam/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
```

The tutorial instructions say:

> If this fails, it means ROS can't find your new package, which may be an issue with your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Please consult the installation instructions for setup from SVN or from binaries, depending how you installed ROS. If you've created or added a package that's outside of the existing package paths, you will need to amend your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable to include that new location. Try re-sourcing your setup.sh in your fuerte_workspace.

I didn't make any effort to " create or add a package that's outside of the existing package paths".

I don't quite understand how

> "Please consult the installation instructions for setup from SVN or from binaries, depending how you installed ROS." helps me since I don't understand what's really happening here.

It seems that maybe the profile command should have listed my /home/sam/fuerte_workspace/ path?!....but I'm not sure.

Please advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44401/rospack-find-beginner_tutorials--failing/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-24**:
Re-opened the question because no answer has been accepted yet. If you see a correct answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out what the real cause of my problems was!
The ROS Fuerte release makes it possible for users not to mess with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH by supplying a "sandbox" directory in the  fuerte workspace...i.e. -  ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
At the URL http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage, section 1.2. Creating a New ROS Package, there is an instruction saying:
Now go into the ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox directory:
$ cd ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox

It then says (and here is where the problem occurs):
***** Alternatively, if you use Fuerte or later release, you can simply do: $ roscd *****

The "alternatively" part led me to believe I could also arrive at the ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox by simply doing $ roscd, but this is not true. One must still explicitly perform $ cd ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox to complete the tutorial. Otherwise doing $ roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp will create the beginner_tutorials directory outside thee sandbox directory. If that is what one really wants to do sometime in the future, then the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable must be modified as stated above, but to complete the tutorials, modifying ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable is unnecessary.

Thank you for all your help! Greatly appreciated!

---

Originally posted by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) with karma: 287 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1